# Can I call the airport to see if my boyfriend made it through customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, airports

My boyfriend is in LAX he came from Australia. His next flight is in 28 minutes and I haven't heard from him at all to know if he made it through customs. I'm extremely scared and I'm having bad panic attacks. I'm supposed to pick him up from the airport tonight and I need to know if he's going to be there or not because the airport is a 40 minute drive.

Edit: He made it through in the end, and was fine.

Comment: What time did his inbound flight land? Did he have a tight transfer time? Are you sure his mobile works in the US? I’ve been in a similar situation (although not in the US), I just went to the airport and waited

Comment: He arrived at 9:33 and his next flight is at 11:58. He's supposed to go on the wifi at the airport and call me. His flight was supposed to get in at 9 but there was a delay

Comment: Do you think it's be okay to call the airport? To at least see if he's on his next flight

Comment: From experience the WiFi at LAX sucks

Comment: How long is the last flight?  That is, how much time is there between the flight's departure and the time you have to leave for the airport for him to let you know if he missed the flight?

Comment: Surely the airport giving out specific passenger information would be a breach of privacy?

Comment: From experience, the WiFi at many US airports sucks—and at almost all American train and bus stations.

Comment: @PeterM I can vouch for this too. I was there in August and my phone couldn't even find the WiFi network. I asked at the information desk and they said "Yes, that seems to happen with some phone models.". Maybe this was the case for the boyfriend's phone too.

Comment: `airport is a 40 minute drive ...` to much of time to give away for boyfriend?

Comment: @Moo If they even have this information. DHS is unlikely to release information to the airport about passengers cleared through customs or not.

Comment: It's easier to check where the flight is or whether it has arrived or not using https://www.flightradar24.com/ or similar sites. Just search for the flight number or airport

Comment: Is there any reason to doubt he'd make it through customs?

Comment: @AzorAhai: Because US border agents are often capricious and cruel, perhaps?

Comment: @R.. Yes, but do they often turn away visitors from 1st world countries with all their documents in order? Basically, my question was, is there anything about his application that might have caused questions?

Comment: For anyone else on tenterhooks like I was - [the boyfriend made it through](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149995/can-i-call-the-airport-to-see-if-my-boyfriend-made-it-through-customs#comment372130_149998) - yay!

Comment: Just ask him to ask a stranger to  use their phone to call/text you, both when he lands, and when he passes through customs (but before he exits). Usually works.

Comment: @smci ideal solution is to have a travel SIM at hand (e.g. Google FI)

Comment: Maybe it got lost in the answers/comments, but why couldn't he just text/call you when he gets through? I understand perhaps he's Australian and it'd be an international call, but surely it'd be worth it to let you know he's made it?

Answer (score 107):

There won't be a way to contact anybody at LAX to see if your boyfriend made it through immigration. In my opinion, the best thing to do is to drive the 40 minutes to the airport under the assumption that everything is fine. If he arrives, great. If not, then you will be in the best place to try to find out where he is - you will be able to talk to the airline agents face-to-face. Trying to find out where he is over the phone will be a lot harder.

Answer (score 24):

It makes the most sense to plan to go to the airport to pick him up. If you don't hear anything, it is more likely that it means he can't call you because he is on the next flight - maybe he had to rush to catch it or whatever and didn't have time in the airport to call. If he misses the flight, he will have plenty of time in the airport to figure out the wifi and call you, or find a pay phone and call you, or whatever.

Comment: He was taken for further questioning and held in a room for a few hours until it was his turn but they let him through thank you guys for the answers

Comment: @Felicia Kennedy Out of interest, and referencing your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149693/what-would-happen-if-told-border-patrol-that-my-boyfriend-was-unemployed what did your bf tell CBP about his employment status?

Comment: He didn't have a surfboard by any chance?

Comment: @FeliciaKennedy Can you put that in the question so everyone who comes to this knows he's okay?

Answer (score 14):

If you have the booking number (and of course his name), you may be able to use the “manage my booking” section of the website to see his status. If the flight has departed without him, some airlines will actually show him as “no show” on the relevant flight. Or you may see him having been rebooked to another flight.

If you have his passport number (and full name and birth date, and his consent), you may be able to check his I94 history online, though I’m not quite sure how fast this is updated.

The airport most probably won’t know anything (but you can of course try calling them, you never know...). The ones who would know (but may be hard pressed to give any information for privacy reasons) are CBP (though I’m not even sure it’s easy to reach the local CBP at LAX), the first airline if he was denied entry, and the second airline if he did indeed go through and boarded the flight or was rebooked to a later flight.

Comment: The I-94 is available immediately upon entry, you can access it online as soon as you are processed into the USA. I tested this scenario on my wife, and hers was online immediately after she cleared customs in JFK. I think its possible to even ask them for a printed one, I have heard sometimes they'll provide you with one if you ask nicely.